# How to change this to a val function

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

```
def nothing(row:Row): Unit = {

}
```

I want to do something like `rdd.foreach(functionHere)`, and I wanted the function to be static-equivalent in Java. I want to change that `def` to a `val` but I just can't figure out the syntax.

I basically want to have java code which is `rdd.foreach(MyScalaClass.nothing())` basically.

How would I accomplish this?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want to pass the function as a variable? If so, you can write a function literal:

`val nothing = (row: Row) => Unit`

and then you invoke it by calling:

```
nothing(aRow)
```

Comment: Great! How do I fill in the method body? In other words the "val nothing" function, how do i fill it in to do stuff based on the row? Also I know this is total noob question, I am completely new to Scala, and cant figure out the syntax :(

Comment: I don't know if I understand since you indicated you wanted a do-nothing function, but if you want a body (that might still return Unit), you would replace, in my example,  'Unit' with {  your code here }. In other words, after the =>  comes the body of your code:  { ...code ...} over 1 or more lines. You do not need to use brackets if your code can fit on a single line after =>

Comment: if you think about a foreach call, and think of an RDD is a "List of Rows" basicaly, you might still want to process the data in each row somehow, even if you don't want to return something. that is my use case.

anyways, your suggestion fixed it, thanks so much

Comment: @Harshil Garg, you already have a handle on some important Scala concepts: in Scala or functional programming terms, you want a function that returns no value but rather performs only side effects.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `val`. `rdd.foreach(MyScalaClass.nothing)` should work fine. Scala will automatically convert the method to a function for you. The Java equivalent of this would be `rdd.foreach(MyScalaClass::nothing)`.